# How can I display a file's text into a desktop line by line using Tkinter module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

community!

I'm writing my own screensaver using Python 2.7 and Tkinter module. Almost done, but stuck with the following problem:

I have a long-long file with, say, .py extension and a lot of code in it, which I want to display line by line into the GUI desktop, using Tkinter module. I managed to do exactly what I want for console using `file.readlines()`, but I cannot find out how to do that in GUI.

I have used a `tk.Text` widget and got the file in full, while I want the lines appear one after another, like when you use `f.readlines()`.

Is there any method to make the `tk.Text` do that?

Comment: "any ideas" is too broad of a question for this site. If you  have a _specific_ question to ask, we might be able to help.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by making a Text box :

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except:
    from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
t=Text(root,height=25,width=100,wrap=WORD)
t.pack()
f=open('a','r')
r=f.readlines()
f.close()
time=1000 # in ms
def f():
    global r
    t.insert(END,r[0])
    r=r[1:]
    t.after(time,f)
f()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, Tarptaeya! I tried exactly the same idea, but it shows me all file in full and not line by line. :( I'd like each line appeared in the screen like they appear when you use f.readlines()

Comment: Try using `wrap=WORD` as the Text widget option ( as I edited in my answer ) . Hope it helps

Comment: Tarptaeya, the same result. :(

Comment: could you post a Screen Shot of your problem

Comment: ![Screenshot of what I get](http://imgur.com/a/egr1n) @Tarptaeya, see, please.

Comment: Do you just want to print a some part ( or some line ) of your file ?

Comment: I want lines to appear one after another. Say, line1 appears, 1 second of delay, line2 adds, 1 second of delay, etc.

Comment: Dear @Vadim , now I edited my code as per your requirements . Hope it works now .

Comment: thank you very much! That works! I did not even think of slices.